# What is an "Exception-controlled" loop?

Tags: java, exception, loops

I'm trying to do a question on my study guide that asks:

> Write an exception-controlled loop that loops until the user enters an
>   integer between 1 and 5.

I can't decipher what this question really means since I've never heard of that term before, but this is my best guess:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;

    while(a <= 0 || a > 5)
    {
        try {
            a = input.nextInt();

            if(a <= 0 || a > 5)
                throw new OutOfRangeException(); //my own Excpt. class
        } catch (OutOfRangeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

What do you you guys think? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The question itself smells for me like it has one freaking big sign on it: `Don't do it!`

Comment: Could it be that the guide means something along these lines: `while(true) {if(input between 1 and 5) {throw Exception();}}` ?

Comment: As a funny note, [you're not the first one wondering about that](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110513111627AAkoPV6).

Comment: Your teacher should be fired for giving out this homework - there are better ways to teach the intricacies of loop behavior. Having said that @ArmenTsirunyan's answer should point you in the right direction.

Comment: My first thought on how to fulfil the specifications was to have a `while(true)` loop which would loop indefinitely and keep on asking for user input if the input is out of range. If the given input is within range, an `InputIsCorrectException` is thrown. Outside the loop, the exception is caught and swallowed.

Comment: @Alderath Personally, I consider `while(true)` loops code smell. It completels nullifies the idea of the loop condition controlling the loop and instead misues exceptions and/or `break` to replace it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that your catch clause should be outside the loop

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int a = 0;
 try
 {
    while(true)
    {       
        a = input.nextInt();
        if(a <= 0 || a > 5)
            throw new OutOfRangeException(); //my own Excpt. class
    } 
 }
 catch (OutOfRangeException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

I haven't actually heard the term "exception controlled loop", but I think it means that it's an infinite loop that exits upon exception. Seems logical.

As the comments say, if you need to loop until the user enters a number between 1 and 5, the condition to throw should be

```
 if(a >= 1 && a <= 5)
```

Comment: @Bobby: I was thinking the same, but then I thought it might be that I understand the word "until" wrong

Comment: The assignment is "that loops until the user enters an integer between 1 and 5.".

Comment: Hm, will the throw cause the catch to be hit and the while loop to be broken? If so, then that will satisfy said condition.

Comment: Also, your conditional range is inverted, should be if(a > 0 && a < 5)

Comment: Thanks Armen, I'm gonna go with your solution and hope for the best!

Answer (score 2):

A really ugly example of an exception-controlled loop:

```
String[] array = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};

try {
    for (int i = 0;;i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    } 
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

}
```

Instead of checking for a condition, and ending execution when the condition doesn't hold anymore, like

```
i < array.length
```

we execute the loop until an exception is thrown. This, ofc, is a really ugly. It clutters the code, and if you call a method inside the loop, which could also throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, the exception would be swallowed.

Comment: Ugh...here's to hoping that I never see something like this.

Answer (score 2):

"Exception-controlled" is not a standard term, and anyway, using exceptions for control flow is a well-known bad practice. But to demonstrate it most clearly (i.e. badly), I would leave out the loop check and just write `while(true)` so that the loop is obviously *only* controlled by the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my dear friend Mr. Big-Number, I was able to dig up [an example for this stuff](http://teddie.socis.ca/~pratt/cisology/guelph/cis2430/notes/09-Exceptions.pdf). Though, I have never heard of that term before, it suddenly makes sense ones you see an example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = 0;
boolean done = false;

while(!done) {
    try {
        number = scanner.nextInt();
        done = true;
    } catch( InPutMisMatchException ex) {
        // tell the user that that's not a number!
    }
}
```

I can't guarantee that this is really what the guide means!

Answer (score 1):

"Exception-controlled loop" probably means loop while exception is being caught, exit when proper input is reached. Though this term seems to have been conjured by that "study guide".

Bobby's answer is almost there, just missing 2 important things in the catch-block to prevent it from going into an infinite loop:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopWhileException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isNumber = false;
        int number = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(!isNumber) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
                number = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Your integer is: " + number);

                scan.close(); // close resources for good practice

                // not true = false, exits loop on integer input
                isNumber = true; // break; can also be used

            } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.print("Input is not a number!\n\n");

                scan.nextLine(); // clears input buffer

                // not false = true, re-enters while loop on catch
                isNumber = false; 
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

As mentioned, looping exceptions like this is generally not accepted practice, but this is just a reference for the so-called "exception-controlled" scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's referring to the technique in this book, which is almost the same technique: Jack Shirazi-Java Performance Tuning (2nd Edition) -O'Reilly Media (2003), Chapter 7.3 Exception-Terminated Loops

link: http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+performance+tuning/Chapter+7.+Loops+Switches+and+Recursion/7.3+Exception-Terminated+Loops

The exception is for optimizing the while loop : when the while condition is not met, the exception exits from the loop without retesting the condition.
But in this case maybe it's not optimization because it uses an if for condition testing instead of while.